# How to add logic to dependency property?

Tags: wpf, logic, dependency-properties

How to convert this property to a dependency property ? Regarding that everybody just said that "Do not use logic in dependency property" and didn't proposed a remedy for that :

```
    public DateTime? SelectedDateGeorgian
    {
        get
        {
           //choose a control based on this "user control" current mode 
           //and return its value
        }


        set
        {
           //choose a control based on this "user control" current mode 
           // and set its property after some manipulations on the value 
        }
    }
```

I want to convert it to this :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateGeorgianProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDateGeorgian", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(MyDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(DateTime?)));

    public DateTime? SelectedDateGeorgian
    {
        get
        {
            //Its prohobited to do something here ! So what should I do ?
            //How should I select a control and return its value here ?
            //I can't have a simple backing variable because I should do some conversion here                 

            return (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateGeorgianProperty);
        }
        set
        {
             //I want to convert received value here and 
             // and after that update some UI properties in this user control

            SetValue(SelectedDateMiladiProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I want to convert the value which is going to be written in this dependency property and also update UIElements.

And also I want to convert a value from an UIElement and return the converted value whenever it's going to be read.

So you see that I can't have a simple backing variable.

Please somebody give me a pattern to implement this.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You have to bind your `UIElement property` to this `DependencyProperty` and use a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). See [How to: Convert Bound Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752091.aspx).

BTW: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx#implications) you can find the reason, why DependencyProperties shouldn't have additional logic in the property wrapper.

**Edit:**

```
<DatePicker Name="dp1"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDateGeorgian,
                                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"}" />
<DatePicker Name="dp2"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDateGeorgian,
                                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}",
                                   Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" />
```

create the converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DateTime?))]
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // your conversions
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // your backconversions
    }
}
```

and add it as a resource:

```
<src:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But this is correct when we speak about outside of the user control. But my problem is inside the user control. :(

Comment: What do you mean? Can you describe the 'inside' problem, maybe with some code?

Comment: I meant that I want to have a user control that converts its values for the users of this user control. And users who use this user control don't care about the conversion logic. I think its apparent in the code provided above.

Comment: Please show the relations with some code, there will be a solution without additional logic in DP.

Comment: A suggestion: make your DP readable for the users and use the converter inside the bindings of your usercontrol childs.

Comment: We have two date pickers (dp1 , dp2) with two separate calendar logic for each of them (At any given time we show only one of them). If we are showing the dp1 then we should return dp1 SelectedDate and when we show dp2 we should convert its date to dp1 calendar system and return it. Is it clear ?<br>And another problem which we didn't attend to it, is that the dependency property is static and doesn't have access to the user control instance belongings(inner user controls and properties). What a mess !!!

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation ;) I managed to solve my problem with **OnSelectedDateGeorgianPropertyChanged**. My designed model can not be shown here by text so I will share its diagram as soon as I have some free time.